# Array (Error) Array: Unrecognized type, may only use numbers or lists, found type Array

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, list, array

I am getting this error when trying to subtract the array with its mean value in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

```
var from = ee.Array([2,3])
var meann = from.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean(),[0])
var to = ee.List.repeat(meann, from.length().get([0]))
var subtraction = from.subtract(to)

print(subtraction)
```

Comment: can you make the error reproducable?

Comment: Do you have the solution for this error?

Comment: `to` is a list, `from` an array, hence the error

Comment: I fixed your error in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is produced because **to** is a list of lists; not a single list. You can fix this with the function in following code.

```
var from = ee.Array([2,3]);
var meann = from.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean(),[0]);

print(meann);

var to = ee.List.repeat(meann, from.length().get([0]));

print(to);

var to = to.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Array(ele).get([0]);
  
});

print(to);

var subtraction = from.subtract(to);

print(subtraction);
```

After running it in GEE code editor, code runs without any issues; as it can be observed in following picture:

[image]